# Getting DUPLICATE error when logging in existing user with Django

Tags: python, django

I've used Django's authentication system to log in users, the only problem is that I get a `1062 DUPLICATE ENTRY` error.

```
def login(request):
    # this will be the first page someone who isn't signed in will see
    form = LoginForms(request.POST)
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username and password:
        #this line returns two values, a user object and a boolean flag 'created', 'true' if user is created and false if user already exists
        try:
            user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, password=password)
            if created:
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                #if the user already exists
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('success')
        except IntegrityError:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('good')

    else:
        return render(request, 'tracker/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Right now I'm just catching the error and basically telling Django to log in anyway. But I know this isn't a good way of doing it, would it make more sense to use `User.objects.get` to test the existence of the user combined with `User.objects.create_user` to make a user if that user doesn't exist?

**EDIT** Added my own attempt, seems to work:

```
def login(request):
    # this will be the first page someone who isn't signed in will see
    form = LoginForms(request.POST)
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username and password:
        exists = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if exists:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('Logged in')
        else:
            User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('created new user') 

    else:
        return render(request, 'tracker/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**EDIT 2** Fixed it so invalid passwords would yield an error

```
def login(request):
    # this will be the first page someone who isn't signed in will see
    form = LoginForms(request.POST)
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username and password:
        exists = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
        if exists:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Logged in')
        else:
            User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('created new user') 
    else:
        return render(request, 'tracker/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the existence you could do

`user = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()`
here `user` will be a `bool`

and to count it

`user = User.objects.filter(username=username).count()`
here `user` will be a `int`.

But you should never get a duplicate `user` you should probably do more checks

here you can check if the exists and also their count if `count` is 1 then only it should `login`.

And if there is no **existence** then only create the `user`

Yea also I would suggest to

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)    
if user:
    login(request,user)
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I forgot about `filter()`. After I asked the question I edited my code to try and figure it out myself, it wasn't working properly until I used `filter()`. Although it's still different than yours, can you tell me what you think of it?

Comment: Yea it will work fine, but about your **duplicate** `user` error, it gonna happen again , I guess

Comment: because if there are more than one users, `exists` will have value and the condition `if exists:` will execute leading to error

Comment: If its a dev environment I suggest delete the redundant user, If it was for testing

Comment: Okay I used `exists()`, and what do you mean by delete the redundant user? You mean after I create it I should immediately delete it?

Comment: No, I mean there are redundant users created, due to previous loophole, you should delete them if you can from admin panel

Comment: One more question: So going from here, I need to also make sure the password matches the username, would I then need another `if` block to authenticate?

Comment: Because right now it's logging the user even with the wrong password

Comment: yea because you should check what user returns while authenticating and proceed with the result, if it authenticated or not

Comment: I just added a small `if user not None` and that worked, I wasn't actually checking to see if the username and passwords matched

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do in that line:

```
            user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, password=password)
```

is to find user in your database, which username matches specified username, and password matches password. But passwords are **not stored** as a plaintext, so basically that lookup will fail every time. When lookup fails, django will try to create new user with specified username and password, but user with given username might already exist.

```
            user,created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for that, I just edited my question and added my own attempt. Do you think that would be better or worse than you answer?